# C for loop iteration

Tags: c, struct

I have a problem writing code which does the following: declare a `struct{char c; int x; }` array and load it with `scanf` via a loop. After it's loaded, a call to function `f` will be made which will replace every occurrence of digits in the struct's component `c` with 0, and will return the sum of the digits replaced by zero.

Code and output are below and I have problem that the loop in the function `f` seems to iterate one time, and it gives out some really weird values.

This is an exam question so I have to use `printf`, `scanf` etc. Also I have that exam in an hour so any quick help is appreciated :)

CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX 2

struct par {
    char c;
    int x;
};

int f(struct par *niz) {
    int i;
    int n=0;
    for(i=0; i<MAX; i++) {
        if(isdigit(niz[i].c)) {
            niz[i].c = niz[i].c-'0';
            printf("niz[i].c = %d\n i = %d", niz[i].c, i);
            n=n+niz[i].c;
            niz[i].c='0';
        }
    }

    return n;
}

void main() {
    int n;
    int i;

    struct par niz[MAX];

    printf("enter\n");

    for(i=0; i<MAX; i++) {
        scanf("%c", &niz[i].c);
        scanf("%d", &niz[i].x);
    }

    n=f(niz);

    for(int i=0; i<MAX; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", niz[i].c);
        printf("%d\n", niz[i].x);
    }
    printf("n = %d\n", n);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
enter
2
2
2
niz[i].c = 2
 i = 048
2
10
2
n = 2
```

Comment: What happens when you step through the code in your debugger ?

Comment: A haven't stepped it, dont know how. All i can tell is that it compiles without any errors or warnings.

Comment: @Sinisa _it compiles without any errors or warnings_ but i can see multiple declaration of `int i` in main. FYI always use `int main()`

Comment: You need to learn how to debug (i.e. how to use a debugger, or at the very least how to add debug printf statements), otherwise you're not going to get very far with learning programming. Every program you write will also need to be debugged.

Comment: Try compiling it with `-Wall` option.

Comment: i do debug with printf (its in the f function), i is declared twice in main according to c99 initializing of variables in a for loop, and honestly i'm learning c just for the sake of school because i'm currently interested alot more in android development and so i'm putting all the focus on java. Thanks to everyone!

Comment: @0xF1 compiling with gcc test.c -std=c99 -Wall gives out following: test.c:35:6: warning: return type of 'main' is not 'int' [-Wmain]. Tnx for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you press enter after the first input, the newline is not scanned by `scanf` and is left in the input buffer. When you then try to read the number `scanf` sees the newline and not a number so doesn't scan anything.

The simple solution to that is to add a leading space in front of the formats:

```
scanf(" %c", &niz[i].c);
scanf(" %d", &niz[i].x);
/*     ^ */
```

This tells `scanf` to skip whitespace.

Comment: It always helps to check the return value of scanf

Comment: That solved the problem, also i just found out i got weird "i" values because a forgot to put a new line after printing it. Thank you, for a fast solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use

`niz[i].c = getchar();`

instead of

`scanf("%c", &niz[i].c);`

or, you can use other better methods for getting `char` input discussed at SO,

Now,
You see second time you provided input only once, that is because the **Enter** you pressed after giving `2` as input to first `char` remained in input buffer, and was read on second iteration.

You are getting `10` as output, because, it is ASCII for `\r`, the Enter. It is **not a digit**, so not replaced to be `'0'`.

Comment: Unfortunately I cant use getchar(), only printf and scanf as i mentioned in the main post. also i figured out the '0' after posting so thats fixed as well :) thanks for input.

Answer (score 1):

I am looking at your code (i am not using console for a decade, but ) here are some insights:

1. try to rename **MAX** with something else

   - do not know your IDE but sometimes **MAX** is reserved
   - and using it as macro can cause problems on some compilers
2. change **scanf("%c", &niz[i].c)** to  **scanf("%c", &(niz[i].c))**

   - just to be shore that correct adsress is send to scanf
3. change **scanf("%d", &niz[i].x)** to **scanf("%i", &(niz[i].x))**
4. change **"%d"** to the correct value (**this is main your problem**)

   - "%c" for char
   - "%i" for int

Try to trace line by line and watch for improper variables change if above points does not help

Comment: I'm using sublime text 2 and minigw gcc, and as far as i know %d is legitimate for integers, didnt have any problems with it so far. Also Joachims suggestion for inserting white space before %d in scanf solved it, so addressing seems to work correctly with scanf, at least for gcc that is.

Comment: "%d" means decimal (any integer type) "%i" is strictly int, i had problems with "%d" in the past so i prefer "%i", scanf with %d instead of %c will change 4 bytes instead of 1 and can overwrite something that should not be... (that is the most probable reason for loop weirdness)

Answer (score 1):

weird values? 
because you forgot "\n" after the line, so next print is behind the line "i = %d".
And, check return value of every function except ones that return void.